# Android Emulator inconsistent

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I have been working on an app that uses camera functionality for a while now, and I have done the bulk of my testing on the android emulator packaged with the most recent SDK. I am not sure if it is from overuse or what, but the camera part of the app that usually works will freeze up sometimes now. I have just added a new library to my app but it is not in the camera activity. I want to know if anyone has any ideas for why the I might get something like the following logcat.

```
06-27 22:25:44.406: E/Trace(787): error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)
06-27 22:28:38.003: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:28:51.472: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:29:09.712: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:29:17.652: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:29:59.582: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:30:27.352: E/Camera(787): Error 100
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1095)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1040)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.example.myapp.camera.CameraPreview.takeSnapshot(CameraPreview.java:279)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.example.myapp.camera.TakePhotoActivity$1.onClick(TakePhotoActivity.java:37)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 22:31:10.763: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

all of the different camera Error 100's are from me going to and from different activities that don't use the camera. When they showed, my SurfaceView inherited class was blank. The error at the end was caused when I had a preview and tried to take the picture.

Here is most of my code for the CameraPreview.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private static final String TAG = CameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean cameraConfigured = false;
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    public boolean inPreview = false;
    public Camera mCamera;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);
        Log.d(TAG, "constructor (context)");
        mContext = context;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        //adding this to SurfaceHolder.Callback
        //to notify class of surface changes
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        this(context, attr, 0);
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

     private Camera getCameraInstance()
     {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCameraInstance()");
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
            Log.d(TAG, "camera opened");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getCameraInstance()", e);
        }

        if(c == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "back facing camera not found");

            //ONLY ALLOW FRONT CAMERA FOR NEXUS 7 TESTING
            Camera.CameraInfo cInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            int cams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            for (int i = 0; i < cams; i++)
            {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cInfo);
                if(cInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                {
                    try {
                        c = Camera.open(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "failed to open front camera", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLayout()");
        if(changed)
        {
            final int width = right - left;
            final int height = bottom - top;
            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;

            Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService
                    (Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            switch(display.getRotation())
            {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                previewWidth = height;
                previewHeight = width;
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                previewWidth = width;
                previewHeight = height;
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                previewWidth = height;
                previewHeight = width;
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                previewWidth = width;
                previewHeight = height;
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                break;

            }
        }
    }


    private void initPreview(int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "initPreview()");
        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            if(!cameraConfigured)
            {
                Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size previewSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, param);
                Camera.Size pictureSize = getBestPictureSize(param);
                if(previewSize != null && pictureSize != null)
                {
                    param.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                    param.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
                    param.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                    mCamera.setParameters(param);
                    requestLayout();
                    cameraConfigured = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
            Camera.Parameters param)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getBestPreviewSize()");
        Camera.Size ret = null;
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetAspect = (double)width / (double)height;
        ArrayList<Camera.Size> matchedPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();         
        for(Camera.Size size : previewSizes)
        {
            double previewAspect = (double) size.width / (double) size.height;
            if(size.width <= width && size.height <= height
                    && Math.abs(targetAspect - previewAspect) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            {
                matchedPreviewSizes.add(size);
            }
        }
        if(!matchedPreviewSizes.isEmpty())
        {
            ret = Collections.max(matchedPreviewSizes, sizeComparator);
        }
        else
        {
            ret = Collections.max(previewSizes, sizeComparator);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters param)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getBestPictureSize()");
        Camera.Size ret = null;
        for(Camera.Size newSize : param.getSupportedPictureSizes())
        {
            if(ret == null)
            {
                ret = newSize;
            }
            else
            {
                int retArea = ret.width * ret.height;
                int newArea = newSize.width * newSize.height;

                if(newArea > retArea)
                {
                   ret = newSize;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(ret.width)+"x"+Integer.toString(ret.height));
        return ret;
    }

    //call by onPause
    public void clearCamera() 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "clearCamera()");
        if(inPreview)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            inPreview = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clearCamera() " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setCamera()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setCamera()");
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }

    public void startPreview()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "startPreview()");
        if(cameraConfigured && mCamera != null)
        {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "start preview", e);
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            inPreview = true;
        }
    } 

    public void takeSnapshot()
    {
        if(inPreview)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "takeSnapshot()");
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
            inPreview = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged()");
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated()");
        //no-op wait for surface changed        
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed()");
        //no-op take care of in activity

    }
```